# Convert Apostrophe to Comma by using numerljs formatter

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, numeral.js

I am using http://numeraljs.com/#format

I need formatter, which can covert number with apostrophe to comma.

Eg: **2'910'724'242** must change to **2,910,724,242**

Is there any formatter available. Or we have to manually convert apostrophe to comma.

Comment: This can easily be done using string.replace but if you want lib's function, would request you to show how you are using it

Answer (score 0):

No need for a library

```js
let str = `2'910'724'242`

let num = (+str.replaceAll("'","")).toLocaleString('en-US'); // replace(/'/g,"") is an alternative to the replaceAll

console.log(num)

str = `2'910'724'242.019999999`

num = (+str.replaceAll("'","")).toLocaleString('en-US', { minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2});

console.log(num)
```

But if you insist

```js
let str = `2'910'724'242`

console.log(
  numeral(+str.replaceAll("'","")).format('0,0')
)  

str = `2'910'724'242.0199999`

console.log(
  numeral(+str.replaceAll("'","")).format('0,0.00')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/numeral.js/1.0.3/numeral.min.js" ></script>
```

Comment: I meant that only. Was going to say i english but then thought to write in JS and got confused. But objective of my comment was to know if using `toLocaleString` gives some advantage

Comment: User wanted thousand separator commas. If you do not use toLocaleString, you will get `2910724242`

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the best way (I'm not familiar with the library) but, since you can't seemingly set the format on parsing, you can change the default:

```js
let input = "2'910'724'242.6666";
numeral.defaultFormat("0'0.00");
let number = numeral(input);
let output = number.format("0,0.00");
console.log("Input: %s; Output: %s", input, output);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/numeral.js/2.0.6/numeral.min.js"></script>
```